# AmCharts4: Merging Points in StepLineSeries

Tags: amcharts4

I have got the following graph:
[image]

Here you can see a graph of a device which is turned on and turned off a short time afterwards. as you can see, there are very short "high" periods. On the 7th Period, the points are so close together that AmCharts just merges them into one. If i zoom in just a little bit more, it will look like this (which is how it should look):

[image]

I did not yet manage to find a property to configure this behaviour.

Comment: That's how the chart works. It scales the points depending on the zoom level and visible period. It looks "merged", but they're just really close together on the axis scale. There isn't a way to "fix" this.

Comment: Well, it is a bug. it shows the data in a way they are not there, I am sure that there is a method to avoid the merging, otherwise AmCharts would not be feasable to display this kind of data.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not a bug but it's hard to definitely say so without seeing your code and sample data. If you can provide that, we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the the reason for this behaviour is this line:

```
 am4core.options.minPolylineStep = 5
```

which I now removed and fixed my problem! It would be interesting to know if this property can be configured independently for series (it does increase performance, so using it for lineSeries is a good idea)